# Looping through data from an NSArray and extracting the UIImage from a url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarray

I have some data online where I'm trying to get a URL of an image and then add those images to an array of images in a `UIPageControl`.

in the line `[carousel setImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", @"3.png", nil]]; the images are set`

I would like to set each of the images. One of the problems I have is that the number of images is not known beforehand. Also the data I'm getting is a string (a url to the image) and not a UIImage.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [publicDataArray count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSString *key in dict) {

     NSString *someString = [[dict objectForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSLog(@"some string %@",someString);

    }

}

NSLog(@"publicDataArray count %lu",(unsigned long)[publicDataArray count]);


    [carousel setImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", @"3.png", nil]];


    // Add carousel to view
    [self.view addSubview:carousel];
```

the `NSLog` output:

```
2013-06-25 11:54:01.094 some string http://***.com/uploads/img/d/1.jpg
2013-06-25 11:54:01.094 some string http://***.com/uploads/img/d/2.jpg
2013-06-25 11:54:01.095 some string http://***.com/uploads/img/d/3.jpg

2013-06-25 11:54:01.097 publicDataArray count 3
```

and my carousel class code .m file:

```
    #import "Carousel.h"

@implementation Carousel

@synthesize pageControl;
@synthesize images;

#pragma mark - Override images setter

- (void)setImages:(NSArray *)newImages
{
    if (newImages != images)
    {
        [newImages retain];
        [images release];
        images = newImages;

        [self setup];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Carousel setup

- (void)setup
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setBounces:NO];

    CGSize scrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.images count]; i++)
    {
        CGRect slideRect = CGRectMake(scrollViewSize.width * i, 0, scrollViewSize.width, scrollViewSize.height);

        UIView *slide = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:slideRect];
        [slide setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];
```

// this is currently causing the crash  reason: '-[UIImageView length]: unrecognized selector //sent to instance.

```
  **UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.images objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [slide addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];**

        [scrollView addSubview:slide];
        [slide release];
    }

    UIPageControl *tempPageControll = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scrollViewSize.height - 20, scrollViewSize.width, 20)];
    [self setPageControl:tempPageControll];
    [tempPageControll release];
    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:[self.images count]];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollViewSize.width * [self.images count], scrollViewSize.height)];

    [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
    [self addSubview:self.pageControl];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:page];
}

#pragma mark - Cleanup

- (void)dealloc
{
    [pageControl release];
    [images release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

thanks for any help

Comment: not getting your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the app while getting the images from server and disable block while loading the images try to use **UIImageView+AFNetworking** library to load the image from server asynchronously [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
NSMutableArray* imageViews= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [publicDataArray count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSString *key in dict)
    {
        NSString *imageUrl = [[dict objectForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:@"url"];

        UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        [myImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"]];

        [imageViews addObject:myImage];
    }   
}

NSLog(@"publicDataArray count %lu",(unsigned long)[publicDataArray count]);

[carousel setImages:[NSArray arrayWithArray:imageViews]];

// Add carousel to view
[self.view addSubview:carousel];
```

Comment: thanks! I do get an error with Instance Method - setImageWithUrl:placeholderImage:' not found (return type defaults to id'

Comment: My mistake; I added that now. The line  [carousel setImages:[NSArray arrayWithArray:imageViews]]; triggers a uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Is that a bounds issue with the array. I'm unsure what that is. thanks again :)

Comment: make sure to deal with images array inside the carousel when you measure the length because this error say that you are trying to measure length of single imageview

Comment: thanks again. I added the code for the carousel class above. I spent a couple hours on it but don't see how the length property is coming into play.

Comment: @hanumanDev if my answer solved your problem please take care to mark it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First get your url in NSMutable array and then get image from URL in following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [publicDataArray count]; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [publicDataArray objectAtIndex:i];

    for(NSString *key in dict)
    {
        NSString *someString = [[dict objectForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:@"url"];

        NSLog(@"some string %@",someString);

        [allProfileImages addObject:someString];
    }
}

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[allProfileImages objectAtIndex:i]]]]];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! what is the object "allProfileImages"? Is that an NSMutableArray?

Comment: NSMutableArray *allProfileImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: @hanumanDev allProfileImages is Array in which URL of all images are stored.

Comment: I declared allProfileImages in the .h file so it's accessible outside of the { } It's returning null though when I NSLog the output. someString is not null and outputs values (urls in this case) for each item it finds.

Comment: allProfileImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];   write this line in viewDidLoad method.